# Access qlikview dashboard in wpf application

Tags: wpf, dashboard, qlikview

I have to create a wpf application in which i need to access qlikview dashboard to view various report data.
Is it possible? If yes, then how can I implement it. Because nothing of that sort is found in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about your QlikView enviroment or how WPF collects data but  the Qlik Analytics Platform sounds like the correct tool for this.

https://www.qlik.com/us/products/qlik-analytics-platform